# What would be the cleaner version of the code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, coding-style

Team mate has written,

```
return ( jsonDict == nil ? nil : [jsonDict mutableCopy] );
```

What would be the cleaner version of the code in `Objective-C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `return [jsonDict mutableCopy];`

If `jsonDict` is nil than calling `mutableCopy` will also produce nil

Comment: For reference, this is a property of `nil` in Objective-C: [any method called on `nil` will have a 0/`nil` return value](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html) [“ Working with nil” section]

Comment: I wonder when then the NPE occurs? Only for accessing variables? @ItaiFerber

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan if you do obj->property and obj is nil. Or if you try to dereference a nil pointer

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Indeed, Objective-C doesn't have Null Pointer Exceptions like Java — invalid accesses of `nil` all involve [_dereferencing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) `nil` (i.e., attempting to access the memory location which `nil` might represent.